# Visitor Pattern Error(use undefined type)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I am studying visiting patterns. However, the following error occurs. not defined.
The cat class only has its own name and age.
agevisitor and namevisitor, which inherit Visitor interface, output age and name.

I tried forward declaration, but the error of C2027 appears as it is. help me :(

that's my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Visitor;

class Cat
{
public:
    Cat(string name, int age) : name_(name), age_(age) {}

    void Speak() {
        cout << "meow" << endl;
    }

    void Accept(Visitor* visitor) {
        cout << "use implementation of visitor" << endl;
        visitor->visit(this); // #undefined type error
    }

public:
    string name_;
    int age_;

public:
    friend class AgeVisitor;
    friend class NameVisitor;
};

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Cat* cat) {}
};

class AgeVisitor : public Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Cat* cat) {
        cout << "cat is " << cat->age_ << "years old" << endl;
    }
};

class NameVisitor : public Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Cat* cat) {
        cout << "cat's name is " << cat->name_ << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cat* first_cat = new Cat{ "kitty", 5 };
    
    Visitor* age_visitor = new AgeVisitor();
    first_cat->Accept(age_visitor);
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Visitor' DesignPattern   C:\Users\sueng\source\repos\DesignPattern\DesignPattern\DesignPattern.cpp   18

Comment: Please show the full error message but presumably you just need to move the definition of `Cat::accept` after the definition of `Visitor`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log into the question. And add a comment on the line in the code where you get the error.

Comment: sorry my Visual Studio is Korean version.

Comment: You can always (and temporarily) change your Windows settings to "English", restart Visual Studio, and rebuild to get English messages. Then you can change back.

Comment: Bus as mentioned by @AlanBirtles, you need to rearrange function definitions (implementations) to make sure that the full definition of the `Visitor` class is available when you use its members. Otherwise the compiler will only know that the `Visitor` class exists, but not anything about its members or its size.

Comment: Thanks for switching to English and starting again.

Comment: I think you've got the point of the visitor pattern a bit backwards and should read some more about its purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of circular dependency like in the Visitor pattern, ideally you should first decompose your code into headers and sources. This is because [forward declared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) classes have incomplete type, so you can use pointers and references to them, you can also use them as return types, but you can't use any of their methods or create an actual instance either on the stack or dynamically, because the class layout is not known at the time.

Example `Cat.hpp`:

```
class Visitor;
class AgeVisitor;  // needed just for the friend declaration
class NamedVisitor;
class Cat
{
public:
    Cat(string name, int age);
    void Accept(Visitor* visitor);  // note that we only declare the class Cat, no methods definitions

public:
    string name_;
    int age_;

public:
    friend class AgeVisitor;
    friend class NameVisitor;
};
```

Then `Visitor.h` and similar in case of `NamedVisitor.h` etc ... :

```
class Cat;
class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Cat* cat);
};
```

And then in `Cat.cpp` you can include the headers with the visitors definitions which allows you to use their methods:

```
#include "Cat.hpp"
#include "Visitor.hpp"

Cat::Cat(string name, int age): name_(name), age_(age) {}

void Cat::Accept(Visitor* visitor) {
    cout << "use implementation of visitor" << endl;
    visitor->visit(this);  // now you can use it, because Visitor class declaration is available
}
```

Alternatively you can copy-paste all the code in the presented order to your `main.cpp` but it's a bad habit. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7PhnfaM3Y) with everything copy-pasted in 1 source.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration of a class without declaring its methods allows only to use the class name in the places which don't need information about the methods of the class. If you use methods (even implicitly, such as calling constructor for the local variable) you need to declare them forward also. E.g. the following code will not compile:

```cs
class A;

class B
{
public:
    B();
};

class C
{
public:
    void Run()
    {
        A* pa; // ok, forward class declaration is enough to declare pointers
        A a;   // compile error, since here we call ctor, but we haven't declared it
        B b;   // ok, we declared ctor
    }
};

// can be in a different file
B::B()
{}
```